# Is HTTLlib2 support NTLM authentication.IF Not what exact explanation for that?

Tags: python, web-services, sharepoint, authentication, ntlm

I am accessing SharePoint data using SharePoint web services through Python application.

Does HTTLlib2 support NTLM authentication?
If not, what's the exact explanation for that?
How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried python-ntlm?

http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/

Comment: i am trying on it.... is that possible to NTLM authentication using ntlmaps-0.9.9.0.1 and remaining authentication like basic will use through httplib2